# Open excel document in java

Tags: java

I want to open excel document from my program in java. Actually I want excel document to be opened when I click on button in my program. I have tried

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("workbook.xls");
```

where workbook.xls is located in the root of project folder, but it doesn't work. Exception says that it can not open program workbook.xls. How can I do this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess you want to open your Excel-file with it's default program (like Excel)? If so, you can use the [`Desktop`-class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)):

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("path/to/your/file.xls"));
```

Comment: I agree. `Desktop.open()` is the way to go.

Comment: Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to work with Microsoft documents. Have a look [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2004/jw-0322-poi.html) for examples on how to use this.

Comment: I think he doesn't want to use Java to work on the excel file, but to hand it over to Excel for opening, like a file browser does.

Comment: The link specified above is gone.