# Using Java, how do I cause Word to open and edit a file?

Tags: java, ms-word

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open excel document in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167585/open-excel-document-in-java)

I have a button in my Java application that, when clicked, should cause Word to open a particular file.  This file is residing somewhere in the filesystem, like in a user's documents directory.

How can I implement something like this in Java?

Comment: Already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167585/open-excel-document-in-java

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is the simple Demo App , you can modify it for button click event :

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] a) {
   try {
     if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
       Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("c:\\a.doc"));
     }
   } catch (IOException ioe) {
     ioe.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

}

This would open word file with default word application . 
More detail here for [Desktop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html)

Comment: *"This would open word file with MS word application ."*  Not if OO is the default consumer for Word docs.  ;)  @Sarah  You might also want to check out the `edit(File)` method of that same class.

Comment: Excellent work.  I'd up-vote, but I already did that before.  ;)

Comment: nice tip, it is simple and easy to open a file

Answer (score 1):

One way is to execute the default program to open the document through the shell.

On Windows:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime()
                .exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler C:/Path/To/Word.doc");
p.waitFor();
System.out.println("Done.");
```

Mac:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open /Documents/word.doc");
```

From - http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html

Comment: There is no need to use rundll for Windows: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("start /Documents/word.doc");`. This assumes that the extension .doc is associated with MS Word. But using the Desktop class is much better as it is platform independent

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I wish you were right. Desktop crashes on some Windows platforms :-( , so this is actually useful.

Comment: @Nathan Hughes: I have neither heard about that nor did I experience it myself and I've used since Java6 was released.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I had it happen here just a few weeks ago, java.awt.Desktop caused my program to crash on a Windows XP machine. Otherwise I most likely wouldn't take this seriously either.