# Is it possible to open a doc file in office word online using java?

Tags: java, office365, .doc

I'm using Spring in my Java EE application . the users of my application can download files , I used a servlet for that . I can also open .txt and photos online using blob .

Is it possible to open a .doc file online using office word online via my java application ?   is there any other solutions ?

Comment: did u try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871664/using-java-how-do-i-cause-word-to-open-and-edit-a-file,

Comment: This would open word file with default word application and the file is residing somewhere in the filesystem but in my case I want to display the file in the browser

Comment: You could try making a POST request to a site that will allow you to view documents online. Take http://www.viewdocsonline.com/ for example. Inspect this site and see where the document is POSTed to. My only other recommendation would be to FTP a document to a server and then use another online application to view it.

Comment: my files are already on the server